# wso2 identity server oauth2 request returns HTTP error 415

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a problem with wso2 identity server that could be a concept error, but I don't really understand what I am doing wrong.

I have a JAVA REST aplication that needs to validate the user with an oauth2 Identification Server. I have installed wso2 Identity Server 5.0.0 on a debian box. I created the end users and created the service provider to obtain the clientid and client secret.

The process I am following is this:

My APP usees the following java code to send the requests:

```
URL url = new URL(desturl);
HttpsURLConnection huc = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
huc.connect();
huc.setConnectTimeout(10000);
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(huc.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
 content += line;
}
```

My app sends the following http request as a POST:

```
https://<wso2is>:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<xxx>&state=xyz&redirect_uri=http://<tomcat>:8080/myapp/rest/listener
```

IS asks the user to login and generates the following request to my app:

```
http://<wso2is>:8080/myapp/rest/listener?state=xyz&code=<xxx>
```

In this step, and with the user logged in my app asks for the user info:

```
https://<wso2is>:9443/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=<xxx>&redirect_uri=http://<wso2is>:8080/myapp/rest/listener&client_id=<xxx>&client_secret=<xxx>
```

Here I get a HTTP 415 response code. This is a format error andin some place I have read that I am suposed to change the Content-Type of the request. I have tried json and xml but didn't work.

I have had this same app working with another IdM that was supposed to be standard (Fiware KeyRock Idm). Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

-- UPDATE --

I have found that adding to the code the following:

```
huc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
```

Gives a different error in the IS sytem logs:

```
No operation matching request path "/oauth2/token" is found
```

But still the same error on the APP side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have changed the way of doing it. Instead of coding the HTTP client by hand I have used Apache OLTU. Much easier this way and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This link[1] will provide necessary request format you want to send. According to your problem content-type should be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

[1]https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3